# Jquery's .before and .after not working on Google Chrome version 49.0.2623.112

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Im just switching the row values of table and the switching works with the latest versions of google chrome

```
$('#downbtn').off('click').on('click', function () {
      if (parseInt(row.children[0].children[1].innerHTML) != table.data().length) {
          CreateMaitenanceCommand();
          var Seq_A = row.children[0].children[1].innerHTML;
          var Seq_B = row.nextElementSibling.children[0].children[1].innerHTML;
          if (row.className == "even selected") {
              row.children[0].children[1].innerHTML = Seq_B;
              row.className = row.className.replace(/\s*even selected\s*/, 'odd selected');
              row.nextElementSibling.className = row.nextElementSibling.className.replace(/\s*odd\s*/, 'even');
              row.nextElementSibling.children[0].children[1].innerHTML = Seq_A;
              row.before(row.nextElementSibling);
               }

          else {
              row.children[0].children[1].innerHTML = Seq_B;
              row.className = row.className.replace(/\s*odd selected\s*/, 'even selected');
              row.nextElementSibling.className = row.nextElementSibling.className.replace(/\s*even\s*/, 'odd');
              row.nextElementSibling.children[0].children[1].innerHTML = Seq_A;
              row.before(row.nextElementSibling);
              }
```

But in the stated google chrome version it prompts an error

> Uncaught TypeError: row.before is not a function

PS : The `CreateMaintenanceCommand()` is just another initialization of buttons that is not directly related on how the rows is being switched.

How can I make this work with the current version of my google chrome?

Comment: Chrome 49? A 2016 version

Comment: I not sure on the year of the version but yeah its really outdated sir.

Comment: that's nothing to do with jQuery since `row` is an element

Comment: childNode.before and childNode.after appear in Chrome version 54 - see [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/before#Browser_compatibility) - that page also has a polyfill (as will the `after` documentaion page) to make your code work in ancient browsers

Comment: thanks sir @JaromandaX but the current requirement is I need to work this switching function to the stated google chrome function.

Comment: yes, so add the polyfill to your code - somewhere in the `head` element add the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/before#Polyfill) in a script tag

Comment: if I were to write an answer it would be "update the browser to the current stable secure version"

Comment: I'd still make it as an accepted answer since you helped me anyway and I think this polyfill will work out.